# Automatically generated Kotlin code (from Java code) loses all blank lines, making the code uglier

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When using IntelliJ IDEA's automatic Java -> Kotlin converter, the blank lines are lost, making the code not that readable. Is there an approach to avoid this or recover the blank lines?

For example,

```
line1;
line2;

line3;
line4;
```

may be converted to something without the blank line at the middle.

Comment: There are currently no settings in IDEA that customize this behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you may do the following:

1. Replace all blank lines with some comment. You may do this by replacing

```
<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>
\s*
<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>
```

with

```
<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>
//newLine
<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>
```

(don't forget to turn on usage of regex):

[image]

2. Convert file from Java->Kotlin
3. Delete comment (replace it with empty string)

Comment: Smart workaround, thanks!